# Convert Calendar to Date - ignore timezone

Tags: java, date, calendar

We receive a GregorianCalendar object from a 3rd party library. We need to turn that into a Date for use in another 3rd party library. And we're on Java 1.6 so we don't have the new time/instant classes available.

The problem is calling Calendar.getTime() gives a different date, offset by (I think) our timezone. So the next day by 8 hours.

How can we do this without this shift?

Update: We get the date from an OData call. The date being returned is an employee birthdate (Northwind) and therefore shouldn't have a time. But it's returned as a GregorianCalendar object with a time of 1992-05-01 00:00:00. GMT timezone it appears.

And the getTime() is returning a Date of "Thu Apr 30 18:00:00 MDT 1992" - I'm in the Mountain Time Zone.

The problem is I need to get from the calendar object a Date object of 1992-05-01, not 1992-04-30. And preferably with the time offset matching too.

Comment: `Date` represents an instant. It doesn't have a time zone.

Comment: So `calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)` doesn't work? ‒ provided `calendar` is your `GregorianCalendar` instance.

Comment: `Date#toString` is a "human readable" representation of the amount of time since the unix epoch that the instance of `Date` represents.  The `Date` object itself doesn't have a concept of a "time zone" or "offset" which are calculations applied "after the fact"

Comment: Well, Calendar.getTime(), as said by the Java documentation, "returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object." So, are you saying you're somehow deriving the date from this, or are you using some other method? Also, which time zone would you like it represented in terms of such that the "shift" does not happen?

Comment: @GigiBayte2 The `java.util.Date` object returned by [`Calendar.getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime())  represents a moment in UTC, but its [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) method confusingly returns a `String` *after* dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone. Thus the confusion behind this Question and many others on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Get get the `Date` value in your default time zone, call [`setTimeZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-).

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.clear();
cal.set(1992,4,1); // 1992-05-01 00:00:00 GMT

// "Fix" time zone
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

*Output*

`Fri May 01 00:00:00 EDT 1992`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

### No shift

```
java.util.Date date = myGregorianCalendar.getTime() ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline. `Date` is in UTC, `GregorianCalendar` may be in some other time zone.
String output = date.toString() ;  // This new string is a lie, dynamically applying the JVM’s current time zone while the `Date` is actually in UTC, always, by definition.
```

There is no shift. Calling `GregorianCalendar.getTime` produced a `java.util.Date`. The `Date` object is always in UTC, by definition. **Unfortunately the `Date::toString` method lies**, injecting the JVM’s current default time zone while producing a String.

Be clear that the `Date` and `String` are two separate distinct objects. One holds a moment in UTC, the other is a textual representation of that moment after being adjusted into some time zone.

The `GregorianCalendar`, the `Date`, and the `String` all represent the same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

### Use *java.time* for clarity

Date-time handling is much easier and clear if you use modern *java.time* classes rather than awful mess that is the legacy classes `Date`, `Calendar`, and `GregorianCalendar`.

## java.time

The `GregorianCalendar` class is one of the troublesome old date-time classes supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Convert from legacy class to modern *java.time* using new methods added to the old classes, specifically `GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`. If using the back-port, use the [`DateTimeUtils`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime( myCalendar ) ;
```

A [`ZonedDateTime`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZonedDateTime.html) object is the replacement for `GregorianCalendar`. This class is conceptually the combination of a [`Instant`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html) (a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) with an assigned time zone, a [`ZoneId`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZoneId.html) object.

If you want the same moment as seen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), extract the [`Instant`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

You can convert back to a `java.util.Date` from an `Instant`, for compatibility with old code not yet updated to *java.time*.

```
java.util.Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate( instant ) ;  // Convert from modern `Instant` class to legacy `Date` class.
```

If you want just the date portion, without the time-of-day and without the time zone, create a [`LocalDate`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

> The problem is calling Calendar.getTime() gives a different date, offset by (I think) our timezone. So the next day by 8 hours.
>
> How can we do this without this shift?
>
> …
>
> And the getTime() is returning a Date of "Thu Apr 30 18:00:00 MDT 1992" - I'm in the Mountain Time Zone.

What you are seeing is an illusion. The `GregorianCalendar::getTime` method returns to you a `java.util.Date` object. Then you implicitly called `toString` on that `Date` object. That `java.util.Date::toString` method has an unfortunate behavior of applying your JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string to represent its value. The value of the `Date` is actually UTC, always UTC, by definition. That `toString` method creates the illusion that the `Date` harbors a time zone when in fact it does not<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup>Actually, the `java.util.Date` class *does* harbor a time zone, but deep within its source code. Used for stuff like the `equals` method implementation. But the class has no getter or setter, so it seems invisible to us. And in the context of your Question, is irrelevant.

Confusing? Yes. This is one of *many* reasons to avoid these terrible old date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes instead.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: If they *"receive a `GregorianCalendar` object from a **3rd party library**"* and they need *"a `Date` for use in another **3rd party library**"*, then adding ThreeTen-Backport is way overkill just for that conversion. Sorry, not a useful answer. -1

Comment: @Andreas (a) Using the *java.time* classes makes the problem, and solution, more clear and obvious. (b) This is not likely their only spot of date-time handling.

Comment: @Andreas We're going to upgrade to Java 1.8 on the new version, but for this issue, I need to fix this in one place in the old version. So yes & thank you.

Comment: @DavidThielen FYI… The idea behind *ThreeTen-Backport* is that the API is virtually the same as *java.time*. You can start using the *java.time* functionality now via the back-port, in Java 6 & 7. When you then move to Java 8 or later, you need do little more than change your `import` statements.

Comment: Since you are going to upgrade to Java 8 anyway, I would certainly consider using the ThreeTen Backport until then advantageous, so you have embarked on the new way of doing things and carry less old-fashioned code over. Up to you, of course.

Comment: And a very well explained answer, BTW.